# Create Pandas TimeSeries from Data, Period-range and aggregation function

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

## Context

I'd like to create a time series (with pandas), to count distinct value of an Id if start and end date are within the considered date.

For sake of legibility, this is a simplified version of the problem.

## Data

Let's define the Data this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'customerId': [
        '1', '1', '1', '2', '2'
    ],
    'id': [
        '1', '2', '3', '1', '2'
    ],
    'startDate': [
        '2000-01', '2000-01', '2000-04', '2000-05', '2000-06',
    ],
    'endDate': [
        '2000-08', '2000-02', '2000-07', '2000-07', '2000-08',
    ],
})
```

And the period range this way:

```
period_range = pd.period_range(start='2000-01', end='2000-07', freq='M')
```

## Objectives

For each customerId, there are several distinct id.
The final aim is to get, for each `date` of the period-range, for each `customerId`, the count of distinct `id` whose `start_date` and `end_date` matches the function `my_date_predicate`.

Simplified definition of `my_date_predicate`:

```
unset_date = pd.to_datetime("1900-01")


def my_date_predicate(date, row):
    return row.startDate <= date and \
           (row.endDate.equals(unset_date) or row.endDate > date)
```

## Awaited result

I'd like a time series result like this:

```
        date customerId customerCount
0   2000-01          1             2
1   2000-01          2             0
2   2000-02          1             1
3   2000-02          2             0
4   2000-03          1             1
5   2000-03          2             0
6   2000-04          1             2
7   2000-04          2             0
8   2000-05          1             2
9   2000-05          2             1
10  2000-06          1             2
11  2000-06          2             2
12  2000-07          1             1
13  2000-07          2             0
```

## Question

How could I use pandas to get such result?

Comment: What aggregate function is `my_date_predicate`?

Comment: Just added the definition of `my_date_predicate`.

Comment: Someone can help please?

Comment: you don't have any records with unset date in your sample data. Would you like to add some so one could see that one's code works well?

Comment: Yes, for instance, we can replace the very last `end_date` with `unset_date` as test (and your solution does not work but if it is replaced priorly by a 'max date').

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
df.startDate = pd.to_datetime(df.startDate)
df.endDate = pd.to_datetime(df.endDate)
df["month"] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row["startDate"], row["endDate"], freq="MS", closed = "left"), axis=1)
df = df.explode("month")

period_range = pd.period_range(start='2000-01', end='2000-07', freq='M')

t = pd.DataFrame(period_range.to_timestamp(), columns=["month"])
customers_df = pd.DataFrame(df.customerId.unique(), columns = ["customerId"])
t = pd.merge(t.assign(dummy=1), customers_df.assign(dummy=1), on = "dummy").drop("dummy", axis=1)
t = pd.merge(t, df, on = ["customerId", "month"], how = "left")
t.groupby(["month", "customerId"]).count()[["id"]].rename(columns={"id": "count"})
```

The result is:

```
                       count
month      customerId       
2000-01-01 1               2
           2               0
2000-02-01 1               1
           2               0
2000-03-01 1               1
           2               0
2000-04-01 1               2
           2               0
2000-05-01 1               2
           2               1
2000-06-01 1               2
           2               2
2000-07-01 1               1
           2               1
```

Note:

- For unset dates, replace the end date with the very last date you're interested in before you start the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for you very interesting answer, it is perfectly working with a little sample. I'm going to challenge it on true big sample today to ensure everything is ok ;)

Comment: great. Please note my last note about unset dates.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working nicely, even with more Data. How could I create a nice plot graph => one line per Customer, with count of employees on Y axis, and month on X axis ?

Comment: you have various plotting libraries. There's matplotlib which is highly popular. I've used plotly in the past and it worked great.

Comment: If it answers the original question, do you mind accepting it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with 2 [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to get the `count` of id per customer in column per start date (and end date) in index. [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) each one with the period_date you are interested in. Substract the pivot for end from the pivot for start. Use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to get the cumulative some of id per customer id. Finally use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and `reset_index` to bring to the wanted shape.

```
#convert to period columns like period_date
df['startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startDate']).dt.to_period('M')
df['endDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endDate']).dt.to_period('M')

#create the pivots
pvs = (df.pivot_table(index='startDate', columns='customerId', values='id', 
                      aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
         .reindex(period_range, fill_value=0)
      )
pve = (df.pivot_table(index='endDate', columns='customerId', values='id', 
                      aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
         .reindex(period_range, fill_value=0)
      )
print (pvs)
customerId  1  2
2000-01     2  0 #two id for customer 1 that start at this month
2000-02     0  0
2000-03     0  0
2000-04     1  0
2000-05     0  1 #one id for customer 2 that start at this month
2000-06     0  1
2000-07     0  0
```

Now you can substract one to the other and use `cumsum` to get the wanted amount per date.

```
res = (pvs - pve).cumsum().stack().reset_index()
res.columns = ['date', 'customerId','customerCount']
print (res)
       date customerId  customerCount
0   2000-01          1              2
1   2000-01          2              0
2   2000-02          1              1
3   2000-02          2              0
4   2000-03          1              1
5   2000-03          2              0
6   2000-04          1              2
7   2000-04          2              0
8   2000-05          1              2
9   2000-05          2              1
10  2000-06          1              2
11  2000-06          2              2
12  2000-07          1              1
13  2000-07          2              1
```

Note really sure how to handle the `unset_date` as I don't see what is used for

Comment: Thanks, should have time to test this today. In the meantime, don't hesitate to upvote the question ;)